# Names for certain numbers.

Tags: terminology

I am wondering if there is names for numbers with the following characteristics:

1. Numbers that end with 0.
2. Numbers divisible by 5.

If there are names for numbers with similar characteristics, I would be happy to learn about them as well. :)

Update:

10, 20, 30, ... is called?

5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ... is called?

Comment: The only digit that ends with $0$ is $0$.

Comment: which happens to be divisible by 5....

Comment: I meant numbers :D

Comment: multiples of $10$?

Comment: so no one word name?

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is "arithmetic progression"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respectively:

(1) Positive multiples of $10$.

(2) Positive multiples of $5$.

If they satisfy both these properties, then they're positive multiples of $10$.

I don't think there are any other names for them, although they each form an **arithmetic progression**, which is a **sequence** of **natural numbers**. If you want to get really fancy, I suppose you could say, respectively, that they're all the numbers *greater than zero* that are:

(1) **zero modulo $10$**

(2) **zero modulo $5$.**

Answer (score 0):

The pattern $0,10,20,...$ is the:

Number of $3\times n$ binary matrices avoiding simultaneously the right angled numbered polyomino patterns (RANPP) $(00;1),(01,1)$ and $(11;0)$. An occurrence of a RANPP $(xy;z)$ in a matrix $A=(a(i,j))$ is a triple $(a(i_1,j_1)$, $a(i_1,j_2)$, $a(i_2,j_1))$ where $i_1<i_2$, $j_1<j_2$ and these elements are in the same relative order as those in the triple $(x,y,z)$. In general, the number of $m\times n\space 0-1$ matrices in question is given by $(n+2)\cdot2^{m-1}+2m(n-1)-2$ for $m>1$ and $n>1$.

That is from [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C10%2C20%2C30%2C40%2C50&language=english&go=Search).